# Adding additional data parameters breaks the afterRender call

Tags: templates, knockout.js

When I add additional data parameters to a template driven div the afterRender call no longer fires.  Here is the call that does not work:

`<div class="parts-results" data-bind="template: { name: 'item.list', afterRender: afterPartsRender, data: { data: parts, viewMode: 'partslist' } }"></div>`

And the call that does work:

`<div class="parts-results" data-bind="template: { name: 'item.list', afterRender: afterPartsRender, data: parts }"></div>`

In both instances, the actual template is rendered correctly, it just does not fire the afterRender when the additional data parameter is passed.  Am I adding the data incorrectly?

Comment: Can you reproduce in jsFiddle?  This looks like it would work fine to me, unless you are getting a binding error, although you said that your template works fine.  Here is a fiddle to work off of: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/4N6fJ/

Comment: I am using the external template koExternalTemplateEngine.js if that makes any difference.